# SQL combining tables with conditional formatting

Tags: postgresql

If I have an index table

```
Index
ID  Last    First
01  Smith   Frank
02  Biden   Joe
03  Trump   Don
```

and another table showing those who meet a certain measure

```
Measure
ID  Last    First
02  Biden   Joe
04  Obama   Barack
```

how can I query this in postgresql to show a listing of those on the index table and their status of meeting the measure?

```
Desired Output
ID  Last    First  Measure
01  Smith   Frank  No
02  Biden   Joe    Yes
03  Trump   Don    No
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a left anti-join approach:

```sql
SELECT
    i.ID,
    i.Last,
    i.First,
    CASE WHEN m.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Measure
FROM "Index" i
LEFT JOIN Measure m
    ON m.Last = i.Last AND m.First = i.First
ORDER BY i.ID;
```

Note that you should, in general, avoid naming your tables and other database objects using reserved SQL keywords like `INDEX`.  I have placed your `INDEX` table into double quotes above for this reason.